# What does <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets> do in a try-convert generated *.csproj?

Tags: c#, .net-5, csproj

I have used the  `try-convert` tool to convert my projects from .NET Framework to .NET 5.0

When inspecting the converted *.csproj files for projects that are targeting `.net50-windows` I noticed the element:

`<ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>`

I am curious to understand what it does?

Is this essential or another example of something that `try-convert` puts in the *.csproj but is not really required to be present in the *.csproj any more?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

The same happened when I used [upgrade-assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-wpf-framework)  to do the upgrade and I also
wondered what the ImportWindowsDesktopTargets means and whether I needed it.  I could find no official documentation for it, only this [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14716).  According to the question in the discussion, adding an ImportWindowsDesktopTargets property is one way to allow multitargetting using the TargetFramworks property, like this:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net472;net5.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
<ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
```

As my project does not need to target multiple frameworks, just net5.0-windows, and as I have other projects, both Windows Forms and WPF, that target only net5.0-windows and work fine without ImportWindowsDesktopTargets, I removed ImportWindowsDesktopTargets from the converted project with no problems.

According to the proposed answer in the linked discussion, even if you do want to target multiple frameworks, there may be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

This is for pre-Net5.0 behavior to force importing WindowsDesktop Targets.
If you are using Net 5.0 or a newer version, Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop will always be imported by the SDK, so you may remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I think try-convert adds it because of a reference to System.Drawing or System.Windows.Forms. [See the sdk section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#implicit-using-directives).